# WPF multiple windows created in different threads

Tags: wpf, multithreading, window

I work on an application which has a main window and some TextBlocks on it. Once user clicks a TextBlock, a new window is created and display the data chart related to that TextBlock. I create such new chart Wndow on a different thread, as following:

```
  private void xTB_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread _displayChartThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Window w = new Window()

            w.Closed += (sender2, e2) =>w.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
            w.Show();

            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
        });

        _displayChartThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        _displayChartThread.IsBackground = true;
        _displayChartThread.Start();
    }
```

The problem is, when you have multiple chart windows open, and you close the main window, the chart windows are still open and not get destroyed. I can see that the chart windows have no knowledge of the main window being their Owner, and I can't set their Owner property to main window in the thread in which chart window is created.

Any ideas on how to handle this? I mean once main window is closed, all the chart window (created in different threads) are also closed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to set the Parent of the new created window to the main window?

Answer (score 1):

You can keep references to the child windows in the main window. When the main window is closed, you can close all the child windows ( invoke `CLose` using the `childWindow.Dispatcher` )